# lots of if statements, need help making some sort of loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone, touchesmoved

I need a quicker way to write this.

```
if(sprite1.position.x==33 && sprite1.position.y==33){
// some code goes here to add sprite1 to an array object at index 0
}
if(sprite2.position.x==33 && sprite2.position.y==33){
// some code goes here to add sprite2 to an array object at index 0
}
if(sprite3.position.x==33 && sprite3.position.y==33){
// some code goes here to add sprite3 to an array object a index 0
}
if(sprite4.position.x==33 && sprite4.position.y==33){
// some code goes here to add sprite4 to an array object at index 0
} ....e.t.c

if(sprite1.position.x==33 && sprite1.position.y==97){
// some code goes here to add sprite1 to an array object at index 1
}
if(sprite2.position.x==33 && sprite2.position.y==97){
// some code goes here to add sprite2 to an array object at index 1
}
```

I have 4 arrays that hold 4 sprites each.

I have 16 points and 16 sprites. Each sprite has been give a random point so I have to check every sprite if it is equal to the point and each sprite has only one point. It is then added to an array. I call the object from the array at object at index 0 as i know for sure that the object at index 0 is a sprite that is equal to point1 which is(33,33). The sprite will be called in cctouchmoved, so i can move the sprite at that point but the array is so i can move a column of sprites as i know that they are all in the right positions. Right now my problem is typing all of that is very long do i have to make a loop or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps store pointers to your 16 sprites in an array, and also have an array of points that you need to check them against. Then have a nested for loop doing the checking. Which sprite hit which point will then be indicated by the current counter of those loops

In this **example** I have not used a point type (eg CGPoint), but a separate array of x points and y points. So any one point you are interested in should be stored in the same element of the two arrays. Eg if you 7th point is (55, 97), then `myXPoints[7] = 55;` and `myYPoints[7] = 97;`

The example loops through your array of 16 sprite pointers. Within each loop, it will loop through the paired array of points. When you have a hit, the loop counters indicate where the hit occurred.

Disclaimer: This only shows a possible technique, and will probably need adapting to accomodate your types and data structures etc.

```
    #define NUMSPRITES 16
    #define NUMPOINTS 16

    // These arrays are to contain the data that will be compared

    int myXPoints [NUMPOINTS];
    int myYPoints [NUMPOINTS];
    Sprite *mySpritePointers [NUMSPRITES];

    // Populate the sprite array with pointers to my sprites
    mySpritePointers [0] = &mySpriteArray[0].Sprite1;
    mySpritePointers [1] = &mySpriteArray[0].Sprite2;
    ... etc ...
    mySpritePointers [15] = &mySpriteArray[3].Sprite4;

    // Populate the points array
    myXPoints [0] = 33;
    ... etc ...
    myXPoints [15] = 97;

    myYPoints [0] = 33;
    ... etc ...
    myYPoints [15] = 97;

    // Now check each sprite
    for (int nSprite = 0;  nSprite < NUMSPRITES;  nSprite++)
    {
        // And check each point
        for (int nPoint = 0;  nPoint < NUMPOINTS;  nPoint++)
        {
            // check this sprite against the x and the y points for this point
            if(mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.x == myXPoints [nPoint] && mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.y == myYPoints [nPoint])
            {
                // some code goes here to add mySpritePointers [nSprite] to an array object at index nPoint
            } 
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Dave, I am kind of confused about '&mySpriteArray' what do i declare it as, an nsarray? and 'mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.x' is there meant to be '->position.x' that in the if statement

Comment: By 'mySpriteArray', I mean whatever object your sprites are currently living in. You have sprites called sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, and sprite4. What object are they in, and what is the instance of that object called? I was 'guessing' that it was called 'mySpriteArray'. All I am trying to do there is get a pointer to that sprite. Do that however you like.

Comment: For '->position.x', it simply means that it is using a pointer to the sprite, rather than the sprite itself.

Comment: @Dave, the sprite pointer '>position.x' is not working says 'stuct CCSprite' has no member names 'position'

Comment: What type is your sprite1, sprite2 etc? The mySpritePointers array needs to be the same type as sprite1, but a pointer to that type.

Comment: Does CCSprite have a member named position?

Comment: @Dave, my sprite 1,2,3 are all ccsprites in a mutable array and mySpritePointers are being added to a mutable array

Comment: mySpritePointers [0] = &mySpriteArray[0].Sprite1; i could not create a pointer like that as it said 'struct nsmutablearray' has no member named sprite1. so i had to use [mySpriteArray objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: mySpritePointers wants to be the same type as your sprites, but a pointer to it. So if your sprite1 is a CCSprite, your mySpritePointers array needs to be a CCSprite*. So it will look like this: CCSprite *mySpritePointers [NUMSPRITES];

Comment: @Dave, I already had it like this 'CCSprite *mySpritePointers [NUMSPRITES];' don't know it just doesn't like this pointer 
'->position.x'

Comment: You could have typed in those 256 ifs by now! So, how is mySpriteArray (or whatever you use to keep sprite1 etc) declared? We just need to get a pointer to those sprites from wherever they are stored.

Comment: @Dave they are stored like this: NSMutableArray *mySpriteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:16];

Comment: OK, where is sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, and sprite4? Are they all members of some other object? If so, you want to do: mySpritePointers[0] = &thatOtherObjectThatTheCCSpritesLiveIn.sprite1; If they are pointers already, don't use the ampersand. If they are private members, then write a method that returns a pointer to them, or declare them as readonly properties and synthesize.

Comment: @Dave i don't get what you mean by members of some other object i've already told you that sprite1,2,3,4 are all separate ccsprites that are stored in a nsmutable array called mySpriteArray. the sprites themselves have been declared and that's all. They aren't actually in anything at all. They are being placed in an array. They aren't pointers either.

Comment: Sorry about asking that twice, but I'm having to do a lot of guesswork about what your code looks like! So the error you're getting is in this line, is it?     mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.x     and everything else is compiling ok? If so, does CCSprite have a member named position? If not, let me know exactly what line it is complaining about.

Comment: @Dave it's giving me an error at this exact line: if (mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.x == myXPoints [nPoint] && mySpritePointers[nSprite]->position.y == myYPoints [nPoint]) { the error message i get is 'struct CCSprite' has no member named 'position' does that mean that i have to decalre position as the mySpritePointers.position

Comment: It means that your CCSprite structure doesn't have a member called position! So I take it your original code listed in your question never compiled, either? I was assuming your CCSprite had a member named position because your original code uses it. I don't know where you got CCSprite from, or what it looks like, but you will need some way of asking your sprites where they currently are.

Comment: @Dave i've got it working instead of putting -> i put ,position.x except for now it compiles but debugger get this error 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds for empty array' but the index number changes each time?

Comment: @Dave as soon as i put in values for nPoint and nSprite it starts working in the for loop if statement. But as soon as i change it back it stops working.

Comment: It sounds like you've only populated positions 0 to 11 in your array.

Comment: @Dave thanks for the help i'll post a different question about the array.

Comment: No worries Dangermouse, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sprite1, sprite2, sprite3 etc, can you not have an array and use sprite[x] in a loop?

```
if(sprite[x].position.x==33 && sprite[x].position.y==33){
// some code goes here
}

if(sprite[x].position.x==33 && sprite[x].position.y==97){
// some code goes here
}
```

Comment: W, when i declare sprite[x] as ccsprite *sprite[x] in the loop; the app crashes when debugging.